# Android connect all mobiles with same App without pairing request

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, pairing

I'm trying to build an App to do it I have to pairing by Bluetooth with all mobiles that have that App, without any request or pin, by code.
I read that if I knew the Bluetooth name of the device I could do a "friendly connect".
So I did this to change the name:

```
 void ChangeDeviceName(){
        Log.i(LOG, "localdevicename : "+bluetoothAdapter.getName()+" localdeviceAddress : "+bluetoothAdapter.getAddress());
        bluetoothAdapter.setName("AppName"+mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());
        Log.i(LOG, "localdevicename : "+bluetoothAdapter.getName()+" localdeviceAddress : "+bluetoothAdapter.getAddress());
    }​
```

Now I can look for all devices that have "AppName" on the Bluetooth Name and do a "friendly connect", how I do a "friendly connect" (pairing by Bluetooth with all mobiles that have that App, without any request or pin, by code, with the Bluetooth Name)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code in

http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.html

This demonstrates the basic idea about how to connect two android devices via bluetooth and send messages between each other.

If you'd like to connect multiple devices without entering PIN code, you need to create a BluetoothSocket for a connection by using **createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord** and listen for the connection by using **listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord**. As the name implies, this allows you to connect android devices in an unsure way (i.e., no need to enter PIN code). Also, I think you need to specify its own UUID for each connection.

Comment: "This demonstrates the basic idea about how to connect two android devices via bluetooth and send messages between each other. " dont you have to pair first the devices on this chat? because i tried one that had too

Comment: That sample app does require manual pairing first. However, you can adapt it to use createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord and listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord so as to connect without entering PIN. My point for showing you that demo is that you should have a big picture for how bluetooth works on android devices.

Comment: The comments confused me much. Is it possible or isn't it possible then to develop an app that exchanges some information with nearby bluetooth devices running the same app, without pairing?